# Prefetch file using parallel processing toolbox in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm new to parallel processing in Matlab. I'd like adjust an existing loop with code:

```
result=[];
load('a.mat','myvar');

for ind=1:100
  result(ind)=myvar; %some computationally 'heavy' function
end
```

While this loop is computing, I would like to pre-fetch the next file called `'b.mat'`. When the loop finishes with the first file, it should check whether the next file is available, and if yes, continue on with the computation.

How can this be achieved? I looked into several tutorials but couldn't find an easy way to achieve this, but was presuming it should be fairly straightforward

Comment: Are all your files named with a sequential character like a, b, c, d, ...?

Comment: Does it take that long to load a file?

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo: not really, all the paths are contained in a cell-array and the there's another loop cycling through the filenames. I didn't include this for simplicity.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Unfortunately yes, datafiles that are several GB, transferred to ram, and stored again on disk after running some computations

Comment: Parallel processing doesn't seem to be a good idea to me. A parfor is enough to achieve it... but parallelizing huge files risks to saturate the available memory very quickly.

Comment: It's what I'm aiming for though, I have an unusual amount of memory (>100gb) that could be used more efficiently (on a server). I know it's easy to use a pareval and load, however I don't know how to make the loop wait or how to structure the code differently, so the loopcode waits for the parfor file-load (in case the file-load is not ready in time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather trying to pre-fetch, it might be simpler simply to wrap `parfor` around your whole loop. That way, each worker loads and then processes a file full of data. E.g.

```
fileNames = ...; % Get a list of files
parfor idx = 1:numel(fileNames)
    data = load(fileNames{idx}, 'myvar');
    result{idx} = doStuff(data.myvar);
end
```

Comment: It turned out, in my case it's not at all that simple =(

Comment: Could it be achieved using timers?